# Do I need WP page titles for all of my pages in Yoast SEO plugin?

Tags: wordpress, seo, title

We have recently installed Yoast SEO plugin in WordPress for our site. And now comes the question, should we add WP page titles to all of the 440+ pages (interviews) manually, is there a sense to make it (each of them has unique title)?? Or it is more important to optimize just the main and most important pages?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the recent update of Yoast SEO plugin it uses your WordPress posts title for the meta title by default so you do not need to go through and enter the title for all of them. However, you should go through them and enter a unique Focus Keyword for each of them also your own Meta description for them.

Answer (score -1):

It's important that the titles have unique, searchable, helpful titles. Google values a good search experience. If you have the available time/resources, it's an investment that plays a small role in your overall SERP rankings.

**Below is a 10,000 hit recommendation.**
*It is just that, a (personal) recommendation.*

• If you are getting < 10,000 hits per month, optimize your 10-50 pages driving the most traffic.

• If you are getting 10,000+ hits per month and have the available time/resources, it's a cheap investment that plays a small role in your overall SERP rankings.

Comment: We have only 967 hits monthly, therefore I am wondering whether it is a good idea to optimize (at least a title) every page, (440+), but thank you a lot!:)

Comment: It will still add value :)